# Can I checkout and commit version 1.8 client and version 1.6 server?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Recently I prepared my work machine. Installed Ubuntu 15.04, openjdk8 and IntelliJ idea 14.1.4.

But IntelliJ requiring svn upgrade. But I can't upgrade server version. Can I commit from version 1.8 working copy to 1.6 repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What `IntelliJ` is requesting is to upgrade the *working copy*, not the server version. There were some incompatible changes to the working copy format when going from `1.6` to `1.7` (and to `1.8`). Running `svn upgrade` will just update the working copy to the new client version and can be used even if the server is still `1.6`.